# migrate bulk insert from sql server to oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

i have to migrate from sql server to oracle database i am obligated to change my bulk query which i use for lot of delimeted csf files. For almost all of various of them i use this below bulk query in sql server. Does anyone know what is equivalent query in oracle database? :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bulk]
    @FileName NVarchar(128),
    @table NVarchar(400)
AS
BEGIN
declare @query NVarchar(max)
    set @Query =N'BULK INSERT ' + N'.' + 
      QUOTENAME(@table) + N' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@FileName , '''')
      + N' WITH ( DATAFILETYPE =  ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'; 
--print @query
exec (@query)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to import data from a file into a table, right?

There are a few ways to do this, but if you're talking about bulk data that you need a high-performance insert on, and it's going to be a regular job, then I would set up an external table. This is query able from the database, and is configured to read the data from the file.

It could be that you then do not need to insert that data into a table, as you can just treat it as a regular table that you can query.

Alternatively you can:

```
insert /*+ append */ into my_database_table
select *
from   my_external_table;
```

If you have a file on a client machine and need to insert it into the database then SQL*Loader would be the tool for you. It's very similar technology to the external table.

Have a look at the Oracle docs, and have a crack at a method that seems suitable, and if you get stuck then ask another question with a sample of the data that you need to insert and your code so far.

Comment: yes what i need is to put data from delimeted files (csv) which have variant number of columns, diffrent separators and so on. For all of them i am using query like in main topic. That;s why i am looking for replaicate my query in oracle. Sql Loader its fine, but what i saw is i need to configure config file with filds required to insert - and this is what i would like to avoid to create each config file for each raw csv file, i would like to not type fields and be more generic as it is in fact with sql server and its fine for all files

Comment: waiting your feedback

Comment: I believe that with SQL*Loader the field list is compulsory.